# No access to system settings from GUI in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, system-settings

I use Ubuntu 22.04 and I have no access to any system settings through my graphical user interface, include display settings, power settings, periphery devices, etc. How can I address this issue.

One way of solving this problem might be a system upgrade to Ubuntu 22.10, but in fact I would like to prefer to stay with the LTS version. I would probably be able to access certain settings through the terminal, but this seems rather impractical. Maybe a simple command or a few lines in the terminal will fix the problem, but I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Has it ever worked, or did it just break recently? This can happen if packages are missing. Try reinstalling the base set with `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt full-upgrade` and then `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` - with the caret (`^`).

Comment: It broke recently. No idea how it happend.

Comment: @popey  I did what you suggested and it worked! Would you like to post it as an answer yourself? Or shall I put it into an answer if you permit me to do so?

Comment: If you still have the terminal open, can you see what got installed? That would help us understand what causes this.

Comment: I still have it open, but there are many pages in the terminal, so cannot print in the forum directly...

Comment: If you can paste it to somewhere like the debian pastebin, then give us the link, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks! That's a ton of stuff that got re-added. Any idea what you may have tried to remove previously which caused this? Perhaps `history | grep apt | grep remove` may help

Comment: looks like I did this:  `sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio`. I am deleting my comment regarding pastebin.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if packages are missing. Try reinstalling the base set with `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt full-upgrade` and then `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` - with the caret (^).