System settings do not show up on Ubuntu 22.04 (gnome-control-center)
I am not able to open my Settings window anymore. When I click on it, it loads for a faw secs but nothing happens. It was completely fine before and I do not remember doing anything special (packages updates or so) since the last time it worked.
Here is the error I get when typing gnome-control-center in the terminal:
gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37: undefined symbol: gbm_bo_create_with_modifiers2

I tried some solutions on former posts such as
sudo apt purge gnome-control-center
sudo apt install gnome-control-center

which does not work.
I have an empty output when running ldd $(which gnome-control-center) | grep local and ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 | grep local.
Ubuntu version: 22.04.4 LTS
Let me know if you need any further details.
Thank you!

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464364/no-access-to-system-settings-from-gui-in-ubuntu-22-04
